# Nuget crash on mono

Tags: ubuntu, crash, mono, nuget

We randomly encounter a crash when running `nuget restore` on mono. It happens on every 10th invocation on average.

Here is some information about our environment:

`NuGet Version: 2.8.7.0`

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.4 (Stable 4.0.4.1/5ab4c0d Tue Aug 25 23:11:51 UTC 2015)
        Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
                TLS:           __thread
                SIGSEGV:       altstack
                Notifications: epoll
                Architecture:  amd64
                Disabled:      none
                Misc:          softdebug
                LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
               GC:            sgen
```

Ubuntu Version:

```
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

And this is the error:

```
...<some successfully installed packages>
18:22:49 Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer 4.0.38'.
18:22:49 Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.OrmLite 4.0.38'.
18:22:49 *** Error in `/usr/bin/cli': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f02fc2be720 ***
18:22:49 Stacktrace:
18:22:49 
18:22:49   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
18:22:49   at (wrapper managed-to-native) zipsharp.NativeUnzip.unzCloseCurrentFile (zipsharp.UnzipHandle) <0xffffffff>
18:22:49   at zipsharp.NativeUnzip.CloseCurrentFile (zipsharp.UnzipHandle) <0x0000f>
18:22:49   at zipsharp.UnzipReadStream.Close () <0x0002f>
18:22:49   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose () <0x00013>
18:22:49   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackagePart.GetStreamCore (System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess) <0x0042a>
18:22:49   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream (System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess) <0x0007e>
18:22:49   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream (System.IO.FileMode) <0x00047>
18:22:49   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream () <0x0004b>
18:22:49   at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage.EnsurePackageFiles () <0x006eb>
18:22:49   at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage.ExtractContents (NuGet.IFileSystem,string) <0x0004b>
18:22:49   at NuGet.Commands.DownloadCommandBase/CommandLineInstallPackageManager.OnExpandFiles (NuGet.PackageOperationEventArgs) <0x00039>
18:22:49   at NuGet.PackageManager.ExecuteInstall (NuGet.IPackage) <0x000ea>
18:22:49   at NuGet.PackageManager.Execute (NuGet.PackageOperation) <0x00177>
18:22:49   at NuGet.PackageManager.Execute (NuGet.IPackage,NuGet.IPackageOperationResolver) <0x000a7>
18:22:49   at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage (NuGet.IPackage,System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName,bool,bool,bool) <0x0010b>
18:22:49   at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage (NuGet.IPackage,bool,bool,bool) <0x00033>
18:22:49   at NuGet.Common.PackageExtractor/<InstallPackage>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () <0x00031>
18:22:49   at NuGet.Common.PackageExtractor.ExecuteLocked (string,System.Action) <0x0006e>
18:22:49   at NuGet.Common.PackageExtractor.InstallPackage (NuGet.IPackageManager,NuGet.IPackage) <0x001b7>
18:22:49   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage (NuGet.IFileSystem,string,NuGet.SemanticVersion,bool,System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1<NuGet.IPackage>) <0x00273>
18:22:49   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand/<ExecuteInParallel>c__AnonStorey0/<ExecuteInParallel>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () <0x0004f>
18:22:49   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<bool>.InnerInvoke () <0x0004f>
18:22:49   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () <0x00046>
18:22:49   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback (object) <0x00055>
18:22:49 Installing 'ServiceStack.ProtoBuf 4.0.38'.
18:22:49 Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.ProtoBuf 4.0.38'.
18:22:49 Installing 'ServiceStack.Server 4.0.38'.
18:22:49   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) <0x0009b>
18:22:49   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00016>
18:22:49   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task&) <0x00109>
18:22:49   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (bool) <0x000ec>
18:22:49   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x0000e>
18:22:49   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.<UnsafeQueueCustomWorkItem>m__0 (object) <0x000b4>
18:22:49   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
18:22:49 
18:22:49 Native stacktrace:
18:22:49 
18:22:49 Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Server 4.0.38'.
18:22:49 Installing 'ServiceStack.Redis 4.0.44'.
18:22:49 Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Redis 4.0.44'.
18:22:50 Successfully installed 'protobuf-net 2.0.0.668'.
18:22:50 Installing 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.44'.
18:22:50    /usr/bin/cli() [0x4b23dc]
18:22:50    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7f0308e2c340]
18:22:50    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39) [0x7f0308a8dcc9]
18:22:50    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f0308a910d8]
18:22:50    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73394) [0x7f0308aca394]
18:22:50    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7f66e) [0x7f0308ad666e]
18:22:50    /usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so(unzCloseCurrentFile+0x6d) [0x7f0305152edd]
18:22:50    [0x417c0814]
18:22:50 
18:22:50 Debug info from gdb:
18:22:50 
18:22:50 Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.44'.
18:22:50 
18:22:50 =================================================================
18:22:50 Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
18:22:50 a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
18:22:50 used by your application.
18:22:50 =================================================================
18:22:50 
18:22:53 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this crash?

Comment: Seems to be a general bug in Mono. Googling `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7f7c41f15340]` brings up a lot.